# OCaml compilation produces obscure warnings about duplicate module - how to remove?

Tags: ocaml

I have an ocaml application that I'm using that is compiled with a library; it is producing a line as follows for every module within Batteries, which is a build requirement of my library:

File "location/to/my/library.cma(ModuleName)", line 1:
Warning 31: files location/to/my/library.cma(ModuleName) and location/to/my/library.cma(ModuleName) both define a module named ModuleName

How do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: What build tool do you use ? Can we see the command used for compilation ?

Comment: Probably this is obvious, but isn't this what would happen if you listed your library twice? Perhaps your build system is handling it for you, so you can remove someplace where you listed it manually.

Comment: @PatJ: OCamlMakefile; hold on I have to edit the command before I open it up.

Yes, and I've checked for that. I think now, after looking over it more closely that it's because there is a collision in recursive dependencies, where the exact version of the Batteries modules differs; one of my libraries that I link uses Batteries, but it ships with it...